# Help interpreting output from glmmTMB and Ben Bolker's overdispersion function

Tags: r, overdispersion, glmmtmb

Just wondering if anyone can help with interpreting the output from Ben Bolker's over-dispersion function (please see link below): 
https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.htmlhttps://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html

Overdispersion function code:

```
`overdisp_fun <- function(model) {
rdf <- df.residual(model)
rp <- residuals(model,type="pearson")
Pearson.chisq <- sum(rp^2)
prat <- Pearson.chisq/rdf
pval <- pchisq(Pearson.chisq, df=rdf, lower.tail=FALSE)
c(chisq=Pearson.chisq,ratio=prat,rdf=rdf,p=pval)
}`
```

My output is:

`chisq       ratio         rdf           p 
285.5999450   0.8842104 323.0000000   0.9339611`

Does a significant p-value indicate overdispersion?

A second estimate is provided in the model itself 
`Overdispersion parameter for nbinom2 family (): 11.3`

Comment: What led you to think you have a significant p-value? What significance level are you using for the test?

Comment: I don't think that this p-value provided within this example is significant (0.93), my question was more if it were significant does that mean I accept the hypothesis of overdispersion?  The p-value is derived using Pearson's chi sq.

Comment: Having that question immediately under the p-value conveys the impression that the p-value is directly related to (indeed prompted) the question...

Comment: If it were significant you would **reject** the hypothesis of *equidispersion* ...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your model, but probably it's not feasible to calculate overdispersion, as your models seems to use a negative binomial family. From the FAQ you referred to:

> Remember that (1) overdispersion is irrelevant for models that estimate a scale parameter (i.e. almost anything but Poisson or binomial: Gaussian, Gamma, negative binomial …) and (2) overdispersion is not estimable (and hence practically irrelevant) for Bernoulli models (= binary data = binomial with N=1).

According to your question related to the p-values: A p-value < .05 indicates overdispersion.

There are some functions to check your "model performance" or quality in the **performance** package, including an implementation of your mentioned overdispersion-check ([see here](https://easystats.github.io/performance/reference/check_overdispersion.html)).